# Text Box User Control in C# Windows Application?

Tags: c#, user-controls, textbox, keypress, onkeypress

In my User Control I have a Text Box which does the validation to take only digits. I place this user control on my form but the Keypress event is not Firing in form.Following is the code in my user control

```
    protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnKeyPress(e);
        if (this.KeyPress != null)
            this.KeyPress(this, e);
    }
 private void txtLocl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyChar!=(char)Keys.Back)
        {
            if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
            {
                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

but in Form also i want keypress event to fire but it is not firing

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        txtNum.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(txtPrprCase1_KeyPress);
    }

    void txtPrprCase1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("KeyPress is fired");
    }
```

but it is not firing. I don't understand what i want to do? It is Urgent for me.

Comment: show me your `TextBox` code plz.

Comment: its already there man.., first one is usercontrol textbox

Comment: i want a `HTML` code of your `textbox`

Comment: i am a windows developer not web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This following override is not needed:

```
protected override void OnKeyPress(KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);
    if (this.KeyPress != null)
        this.KeyPress(this, e);
}
```

Because `base.OnKeyPress(e);` will fire the attached event. You don't need to do it manually.

Instead call `OnKeyPress` of user control in the text-box's event handler:

```
private void txtLocl_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnKeyPress(e);

    if (e.KeyChar!=(char)Keys.Back)
    {
        if (!char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the event handler code in your Form_Load event, or using the Form Designer to create the event handler (it's in the lightning icon on the properties page).